# Disable the Power button on a Chromebook

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, chrome-book

I have a Chromebook on which I installed Arch Linux. However, this Chromebook comes with a very odd key: a "Power On/Off" key at the top right of the keyboard. Without ANY warning, this button turns off the computer. Naturally, I have been pressing this key when looking for backspace or when my finger slipped while pressing surrounding buttons. As a consequence, I have turned off my computer at very impractical moments. This has to stop.

How can I disable or remap this key?

[image]

Comment: I have never noticed that about Chromebooks. What an awful design...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found your solution on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices#Power_key_and_lid_switch_handling):

> Out of the box, `systemd-logind` will catch power key and lid switch
>   events and handle them: it will shut down the Chromebook on a power
>   key press, and a suspend on a lid close. However, this policy might be
>   a bit harsh given that the power key is an ordinary key at the top
>   right of the keyboard that might be pressed accidentally.
>
> To configure `logind` to ignore power key presses and lid switches, add
>   the lines to `logind.conf` below.
>
> `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
>
> ```
> HandlePowerKey=ignore
> HandleLidSwitch=ignore
> ```
>
> Then restart `logind` for the changes to take effect.

It looks like you just need to add `HandlePowerKey=ignore` to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

First you could edit your keymap file to change the behavior of the power button to assign it to an other key

Edit the file : `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` (edit POWR key)

Then you will need to disable the power button efficiently a good method is with xinput

run `xinput --list` power buttons have their own entry... pick the device number then run

`xinput disable devnumber` something like `xinput disable 8`